# Fullscreen WinJS.UI.FlipView?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

The FlipView's docs mention that it needs an absolute size in order to render, but I was able to get it to work with percentages (100%s to be exact). But whatever I do, I can't seem to get an <img> tag that lies inside the flipview to fully scale as well. Instead, it stays small and centered within the flipview. I know it's possible because there are already existing applications that do this (most photo-viewing apps for example), but I can't seem to figure it out on my own, and the docs aren't much help. Any tips?

Comment: Why not set 100%/100% on the image itself?

Comment: It doesn't work, rather it just sets the image to its maximum size. Funny thing, I later learned that the images I was bringing in weren't actually very large, so it was a good thing that they weren't being scaled to full (would've lead to pixelation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `vh` and `vw` units

```
.flipview {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
```